# Deep Learning Sequence 2 Sequence models

Tags: deep-learning

I have a general question concerning seq2seq models. There are lots of Open Source Tools like TensorFlow, Torch and others. But I did not find an answer for my question:

Is it possible to add training data to a once trained model without starting the whole training process from the beginning?

Comment: you can initialize the weights with that of trained model and start training on your data. Did you already try it?

Comment: @Krishna: no thanks, I didn't try it, but that is a good idea!